# How to create new column with nuniqe values per ID in other column and do not count defined value in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below (ID and COL1 is "object" data type):

| ID | COL1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | XX |
| 123 | XX |
| 123 | L |
| 456 | AP |
| 456 | AP |
| 77 | C |
| 88 | LACK |
| 66 | LACK |
| 66 | G |

And I need to create new column "COL1_bis" where will be infromation how many unique values in "COL1" has each ID.
**But if some ID has value "LACK" in "COL1" then we do not count that**

So as a result I need something like below:

| ID | COL1 | COL1_bis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | XX | 2 |
| 123 | XX | 2 |
| 123 | L | 2 |
| 456 | AP | 1 |
| 456 | AP | 1 |
| 77 | C | 1 |
| 88 | LACK | 0 |
| 66 | LACK | 1 |
| 66 | GG | 1 |

Because:

- ID = 123 has 2 in COL1_bis, because this ID has 2 different (unique) values in COL1: "XX" and "L"
- ID = 456 has 1 in COL1_bis, because this ID has 1 unique value in COL1: "AP"
- ID = 77 has 1 in COL1_bis, because this ID has 1 unique value in COL1: "C"
- ID = 88 has 0 in COL1_bis, because this ID has value "LACK" in COL1, so we do not count this value
- ID = 66 has 1 in COL1_bis, because this ID has "LACK" in COL1 and "GG" so we count only "GG"

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['COL1'].transform('nunique')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace `LACK` to missing values and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df['COL1_bis'] = (df['COL1'].mask(df['COL1'].eq('LACK'))
                            .groupby(df['ID'])
                            .transform('nunique'))
print (df)
    ID  COL1  COL1_bis
0  123    XX         2
1  123    XX         2
2  123     L         2
3  456    AP         1
4  456    AP         1
5   77     C         1
6   88  LACK         0
7   66  LACK         1
8   66     G         1
```